# SocketIO dont fire first client events

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io, ionic3

I am building a chat app. The issue is that, `socket.io` does not `emit`the `keypress` event on the first client, when fired.

I built this with `Ionic 3` & `Angular 5`

[Here's](https://thumb.gyazo.com/thumb/800_w/_deddb876ffc5e13958c861986d8f405a-gif) the "bug"

My view.html

```
 <p *ngIf="typing == true">... is typing</p>
 <ion-item no-lines>
   <ion-input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Message"
       [(ngModel)]="message"
       (keypress)="userIsTyping()">
   </ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

My view.ts

```
userIsTyping() {
  this.socket.emit('typing');
  this.socket.on("updateTyping", (data) => {
    console.log('typingInSocket = ' + data.isTyping);
    this.typing = data.isTyping;
  });
  console.log('typing = ' + this.typing);
```

My server.js

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('typing', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('updateTyping', {
      isTyping: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      socket.broadcast.emit('updateTyping', {
        isTyping: false
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

Do you have any solution ?
Thanks you guys !

Comment: If you click into the input box of each screen, without typing anything, then go back to the first one, does it work? It appears to me that the client socket.io doesn't connect until you put focus in the window. I find it odd that `typing=false` comes up in the left window but not the right. I also find it odd that that comes up at all seeing as I assume there's been no keypress so far

Comment: @MattFletcher "typing=false" appear on the first keypress, the gif skip 1s of the start :x
I was hoping it was only a window focus problem, but that's not the problem. i past all my day on this without solution i'm so sad

Comment: Oh I've just realised what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the issue is how you're going about defining your socket listener. You're setting the event listener for `this.socket.on("updateTyping")` *inside* the block of code that only runs once you start typing. So every time you start typing, you *create a new duplicate* event listener. However, because it's only defined when you start typing, the "is typing..." won't show up until you've typed at least one character, at which point it'll start listening.

The answer is basically to move that socket listener outside of the `userIsTyping()` function.

```
this.socket.on("updateTyping", (data) => {
  console.log('typingInSocket = ' + data.isTyping);
  this.typing = data.isTyping;
});

userIsTyping() {
  this.socket.emit('typing');
}
```